# OpenCV similarity between two images using Euclidean distance

Tags: opencv

Can we use the Euclidean distance to determine the similarity between two images

- Detect Keypoint image1, image2 using SUFT
- Compute Descriptor image1, image2 using SUFT
- double dif = norm(des1,des2,L2_norm)----> if dif is small -> can we tell that two images similar?

If yes, so what is the threshold to lead to these two images are similar.

And another question is when I compute descriptor for those images.
I see that the size of them is not equal. Ex: des1 is 64x96, des2 is 64x85
So the norm function throw an exception.

So is there any way for us to normalize the descriptor to fixed size in order to using Euclidean distance or not?

And I use OpenCV Java API to do these above stuffs currently.

Comment: 1) You need global descriptors to compare images, not local ones (btw, SUFT doesn't exists, SIFT or SURF maybe...). You can for example using Bag of Words approach, computing the global descriptor using your SIFT and compare the two global descriptors. 2) No golden rule for the threshold. 3) With global descriptors you compare desc with the same size and prevent those problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to use Bag of Words.